# Showing/hiding directives content on model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for some help with a directive I'm trying to get to work

What i'm trying to achieve:
Show a directive  which will be hidden until the notification factory is called and then the notification will be shown with the error css class (makes it look like an error notification) or the notification css class (makes it look like an normal/success notification)

The problem is that my directive shows well if I just show it. But when I use the ng-if or ng-show/hide functionality the view doesn't seem to react to it. Just when you update a controller value outside of a $digest cycle. I've tried catching it with a $watch but that doesn't work for me either.
Directive:

```
angular.module('App').directive('notification', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/shared/notification.html',
        controller: 'notificationController as notification',

    }


})
```

Controller:

```
.controller('notificationController', ['notificationFactory',
    function notificationController(notificationFactory) {

        this.notification = notificationFactory.notification;
        this.closeNotification = notificationFactory.closeNotification();

    }])
```

Factory:

```
.factory('notificationFactory', ['$ionicLoading', '$ionicPopup', '$ionicModal',
    function notificationFactory($ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $ionicModal) {

        notificationFactory.notification = {
            text: '',
            error: false,
            show: false
        };

        //show notification
        notificationFactory.showNotification = function (text, error) {
            notificationFactory.notification.text = text || '';
            notificationFactory.notification.error = error || '';
            notificationFactory.notification.show = true;
            //$scope.apply();
            console.log('sfsfds')
        }

        //close notification
        notificationFactory.closeNotification = function () {
            notificationFactory.notification = {
                text: '',
                error: false,
                show: false
            };
        }
    }]);
```

View (part of another view that has a different controller):

```
<notification>
    <div ng-if="notification.notification.show" class="error">
        <a ng-click="notification.closeNotification()">x</a>
        <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</b></p>
        <p>
            {{notification.notification.text}}<br /> adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
        </p>
        {{notification.notification.error}}
    </div>

    <div ng-if="notification.notification.show && !notification.notification.error" class="notification">
        <a ng-click="notification.closeNotification()">x</a>
        <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</b></p>
        <p>
            {{notification.text}}consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
        </p>
        {{notification.error}}
    </div>

    error: <p>{{notification.notification.error}}></p>
    text: <p>{{notification.notification.text}}></p>
    show: <p>{{notification.notification.show}}></p>
</notification>
```

I've been trying some suggestions I've found around the web as in entering the $watch in the directive link function and also trying to set the `scope: {notification: '='} but I'm not quite there yet.

Can someone please assist?

Many thanks.

Comment: could you make a plunk?

Comment: Sure, here you go [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xCM6G15RBe0CsojYpc75?p=preview). What you see is that I have a view with a controller of viewController and when i click the testbutton the notificationShow is called in the notificationfactory. It does get to that method and update the notificationController.notification object but doesnt seem to update the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems. Firstly, in the `closeNotification` method you replace the `notification` object, whereas the scope of the directive keeps pointing to the original and gets detached. On top of that you made a typo at the `notificationController`, calling that method instead of assigning. Which leads to the directive's notification getting instantly detached from any notification changes.